# React Router 6.15.0 does not render anything at all while a loader is fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my React application using Vite, I have created a basic router using `react-router` with a parent element rendering my root layout with an `Outlet` inside it, and a loader on the first child of the parent route. The problem is that when I navigate on my child element, the application does not render anything at all, just a white screen, until the loader is done fetching the data. My application is structured as shown below.

App.js

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children:
    [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <HomePage />,
        loader: getApplications
      },
      {
        path: 'application/:applicationID',
        element: <h2>Single application page</h2>,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    element: <LoginPage />,
    action: userLogin
  }
]);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ToastContainer
        position='top-right'
        autoClose={5000}
        hideProgressBar={true}
        newestOnTop={true}
        closeOnClick={true}
        rtl={false}
        pauseOnFocusLoss
        draggable
        pauseOnHover
        theme='colored'
      />
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Root.js

```js
const RootLayout = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  const isPageLoading = navigation.state === 'loading';

  console.log(isPageLoading);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) {
      navigate('/login');
    }
  }, [token, navigate]);

  if (token) {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Navbar />

        <Layout>
          <PageContent>
            {isPageLoading
              ? <LoadingSpinner />
              : <Outlet />
            }
          </PageContent>

          <PageFooter />
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
};

export default RootLayout;
```

Home.js

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const data = useLoaderData();

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <>
      <PageHeader pageTitle='Αιτήσεις' hasBack={false} />
    </>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

applicationLoader.js

```js
const getApplications = async () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  let data = {};

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(appsEndPoint(), {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `token ${token}`
      },
      timeout: 30000
    });

    data = response.data;

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    if (isAxiosError(error)) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error(error.message);
      return null;
    }
  }
};

export default getApplications;
```

I recently created the exact same login with the help of a course and it works jus fine, it renders the `RootLayout` while displaying a loading spinner, and after the loader is done fetching it renders the outlet with the data on the screen just us expected. But for some reason on my own application, it just displays nothing at all until the data is there, and then just spits everything on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loader functions are called ***prior*** to a route loading. In other words, the loader completes and returns the fetched data ***then*** the route is loaded with the data available to it. Seems you want to defer the fetching and load the route immediately so you can display a loading indication *while* the data is being fetched. Check the [Deferred Data Guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/deferred).

Here's an example refactor of your code to do this:

```
import { defer } from "react-router-dom";

const getApplications = async () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem( 'token' );

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(appsEndPoint(), {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `token ${ token }`
      },
      timeout: 30000
    });

    return response.data;
  } catch(error) {
    if (isAxiosError(error)) {
      console.log(error);
      toast.error(error.message);
    }
    throw error;
  }
};

const getApplicationsDeferred = () => {
  return defer({
    applications: getApplications(),
  });
};

export default getApplicationsDeferred;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Await, useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";

const HomePage = () => {
  const data = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinner />}>
      <Await
        resolve={data.applications}
        errorElement={<p>Error loading applications.</p>}
      >
        {(applications) => {
          console.log(applications);

          return (
            <>
              ...
              <PageHeader pageTitle='Αιτήσεις' hasBack={ false } />
              ...
            </>
          )
        }}
      </Await>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

You now probably don't need the "loading" UI in the root layout, just unconditionally render the `Outlet` so the nested routes are immediately available/reachable.

```
<Layout>
  <Navbar />

  <Layout>
    <PageContent>
      <Outlet />
    </PageContent>

    <PageFooter />
  </Layout>
</Layout>
```

Here's a running demo, it fetches fake JSON data for demo purposes, but the asynchronous data/loading flow is the same.

[image: Edit exciting-platform-txq5q6]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your time and effort.
I do understand how defer, Await and Suspense work, and I was about to implement the same logic for my pages to work. What grinds my gears though is that a few days before I started my project, I watched a Udemy course that followed exactly the same logic as the one I described in my issue, and it worked as expected. It loaded the RootLayout, and in the Outlet's place a loading spinner until the data from the API was available. The teacher used react router 16.12. I tried using the same version but with no results.